# Liquibase generateChangeLog on SQLServer DB fails on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS

Tags: liquibase

I installed Liquibase on an AWS EC2 Linux server and used it on SQL Server databases using the commands update and also generateChangeLog sucessfully.

After installing the hana client (/usr/sap/hdbclient) and the Liquibase hana extension (/opt/Liquibase/liquibase-hanadb-2.0.jar) generateChangeLog no longer works for SQL Server databases. The update command stills work fine for SQL Server.

The generateChangeLog and the update commands are both working for HANA databases.

The problem seems to be that generateChangeLog on SQLServer is now attempting to access a non-existent object, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS.

I issue the command:

```
liquibase  --changeLogFile=./MY_MSSQL_DB.xml --url="jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-ris-ods-qa.ucsd.edu:1433;databaseName=MY_MSSQL_DB" --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --classpath="/opt/sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar" --username=MSSQL_USER --password=******** generateChangeLog
```

I get a verbose error which references information_schema.constraints and also the liquibase hana extension at the end:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name
>   'information_schema.constraints'.
>   liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name
>   'information_schema.constraints'.

Comment: Possibly something to do with the collation type being case sensitive.. note the object is called `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS` not `information_schema.constraints` as per the error message...

Comment: As the call is generated by Liquibase I can't do anything about the case. There isn't any system view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS or information_schema.constraints in the database. From SSMS I can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table with upper or lower case.

Comment: I'm not clear why the hana extension is being used on a SQL Server database.

Comment: The problem was solved by removing the HANA extension file liquibase-hanadb-2.0.jar from the /opt/Liquibase directory where the liquibase executable is.

Comment: I thought that I could have the liquibase.jar file and the liquibase-hanadb-2.0.jar file in the same directory. It seems I was mistaken. I believe I will need to have another installation of Liquibase just for SAP HANA databases. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That worked. Just for SAP HANA databases I created an /opt/Liquibase-hanadb directory. This has both the liquibase.jar file and the liquibase-hanadb-2.0.jar files.